# OpenCV VideoCapture buffer and read time

Tags: opencv, buffer

I am trying to read images from an USB camera 8Mp with `VideoCapture` in Python using `cap.read()`. Time is really critical.

There is an internal buffer in openCV of 5 frames, so when an image is requested, I have to make 4 `cap.grab()` and then one `cap.read()` to reduce time to its minimum.

In the file *cap_libv4l.cpp*, there is a variable `DEFAULT_V4L_BUFFERS (#define DEFAULT_V4L_BUFFERS 4)`.

I changed it and have recompiled OpenCV.

`#define DEFAULT_V4L_BUFFERS 0` is not allowed, it gives an error.

If I change it to `#define DEFAULT_V4L_BUFFERS 1`, I just need to make one `cap.grab()` and one `cap.read()` but time doesn't reduce.

When you reduce the value of `DEFAULT_V4L_BUFFERS` then time of `cap.read()` increase, being the same total time in both cases: buffer size 4 (4 grabs and 1 read) and buffer size 1 (1 grab and 1 read).

Does someone know why this happens? Is there any way to reduce the capture time besides using threads? I tested threads but then I face the "select timeout" problem capturing images.